# How to access elements in an Object which nested in an array of State in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React, and today I encountered a problem. I tried to fetch data from an api, everything went well untill I changed the 'character' from an object to an array. After it, my jsx no longer could access elements from the state.

The snippet of the original code is as follow:

```
//When the state 'character' is an object

class Api extends React.Component {
    state = {
        loading: false,
        character: {}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/1')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState(
                    {
                        character: data,
                        loading: false
                    }
                );
                console.log('newstate', this.state.character);
            });
    }
    render() {
        return (
    <div><h3>Name: {this.state.character.name}</h3>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Later, I wanted to imporve the data structure, so I changed the 'character' state to an Array, according which I changed the way to access the 'character', turned out it's no longer works.

```
// after I changed the type of 'character'

class Api extends React.Component {
    state = {
        loading: false,
        character: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/1')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState(
                    {
                        character: this.state.character.concat(data),
                        loading: false
                    }
                );
                console.log('newstate', this.state.character);
            });
    }
    render() {
        return (
    <div><h3>Name: {this.state.character[0].name}</h3>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Are you getting any particular errors?

Comment: can you share the data you are getting from API

Comment: share here your: console.log('newstate', this.state.character); this.state.character after fetch

Comment: On a somewhat related note, `setState` takes a callback as its second argument. Since state updates are asynchronous it's a good idea to put your `console.log` statement inside such a callback. Otherwise the console output might not reflect your latest `state` changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked with an object because you tried to access a property that doesn't exist on the object and got `undefined` instead

When you try to access the data before the http request finishes, `array[0]` is `undefined` and will throw an error when you try to access a property on `undefined`

There are a couple of ways you can make it work, when using arrays you can just map over the array and render the elements, if the array is empty nothing will be rendered

```js
<div>
  {this.state.character.map(char => (
    <h3 key={char.name}>Name: {char.name}</h3> // don't forget the key
  )}
</div>
```

You can also check if there is an element inside the array before trying to access a property on the element if you only want to render the first element

```js
<div>
  {this.state.character[0] && (
    <h3>Name: {this.state.character[0].name}</h3>
  )}
</div>
```

But, it looks like you are storing a single character inside the array and it will make sense to just keep it as an object, use arrays when you need to store multiple items instead of just one

Comment: Thank you. You are right and it worked after your guide.

Answer (score 0):

For updating the state based on the previous state, you should use a function instead of an object:

```js
this.setState(state => (
  {
    character: state.character.concat(data),
    loading: false
  }
), () => {
  console.log(this.state);
});
```

Note that react state updates may be asynchronous, that's why I added a callback to my example for tracing the new state.

You can read more about React state and lifecycle in the official documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly